# Ceiling fan stops and light turns off

Tags: ceiling-fan

My ceiling fan and light will run briefly, then shut off.
Will not run again unless the wall switch is off for a certain amount of time.
This is the light and the fan.

Hunter fan, integrated light. Single wall on/off switch.
Remote only, no pull chains.
This fan is 3 or 4 years old and worked with no issues until recently.

I replaced the remote unit in the fan, now just the light comes on.
The hand held remote does nothing.

Comment: Would turn off the breaker and check all the connections on the switch and fan for tightest.

Comment: What type/brand/model switch? What type/brand/model fan? What type/brand/model light (unless integrated with the fan)?

Comment: This could be the result of wiring the fan and light in series with each other. The LED's electronic ballast does what it can with the voltage available to it at the fan's locked rotor current, then as voltage drops even further with higher fan speed, the ballast gives up and shuts down until reset by powering down. Anyone here who thinks this could be the reason and wants to run with it to explain correct wiring to @terry, feel free.

Comment: @MTA integrated light, remote only

Comment: Is this a new fan installation or an old one that was working correctly?

Comment: @Ruskes Yes, with separate leads for light and fan that can be connected the wrong way.

Comment: @MTA, so the fan goes on when you push lights on remote ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the remote in the fan is failing.

Is it new ? under warranty ? replace it, or the whole fan.

For some reason the remote unit mounted in the fan is  shutting down.

When you turn off the wall switch you cut the power incoming to the remote, so the circuits can cool down.

They are not repairable, only replaceable.

If you want to test it, disconnect the fan wire and leave the lights on to see if they stay. Then reverse the process.

Comment: hunter fan, integrated light, remote only.
single on/off wall switch.

Comment: Did you put a bigger bulb in? Also try lubricating the fan.